# sameSite=None; Secure still facing issue on Safari versions above 13

Tags: security, cookies, safari, samesite

Even after adding sameSite=None; Secure , latest safari version 13 on MacOS 10.15 , **still seeing an issue of session timed out**  with third party cookies, and chrome works really well with this approach. Is this expected ?  for sure no from below link. Could you please confirm , if any one has faced similar issue.

Any support would be really appreciated.

https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/incompatible-clients

After checking on https://samesite-sandbox.glitch.me/

[image]

Comment: Are you able to include an example or site the demonstrates this behaviour? As far as I'm aware, Safari should effectively ignore the `SameSite=None` value, i.e. treat it like a normal cookie. What do you see if you visit https://samesite-sandbox.glitch.me ?

Comment: H Rowan, Thanks for replying. Please find above for the attachment in the description for latest 10.15 MacOS .Would you be able to suggest anything from it ! Sample url https://uk.monsoon.co.uk/ can be used for reference .

Let me know . Thanks

Comment: Did you upgrade Safari to 13.1?

Comment: Yup we tried with safari 13.1

Comment: @rowan_m Hi Rowan , any further inputs would be really helpful. Many thanks

Comment: @vij I'm facing samesite bug in Safari latest as well. Do you manage to resolve it?

Comment: hey Vivek, is the issue revolving around any specific third party ? or is it with all the integrations? I haven’t done any change for the latest version specifically, but for one of the third party we changed the way we interact with it.